# How do you check the size of a tar archive before saving it without doing the compression twice?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script that will compress directory, and will check if there is space on the disk for the directory that needs to be compressed. The problem that I'm running into is that I can't find that out without first compressing the file and passing it to wc, and then if the condition passes, compress the file again, making the PC do the compression twice for no reason.

Current code:

```
EMPTY_SPACE=$(df -k . | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}')
ARCHIVE_SIZE=$(( $(tar czf - "$1" | wc -c )/1000 ))
if [ $EMPTY_SPACE -lt $ARCHIVE_SIZE ]; then
    echo "Not enough disk space to save the archive"
    exit 6
fi
tar czf ${1%/}".tar.gz" $1
```

What I would like to do is have some kind of conditional tee or the sort that would only fire if the `[ $EMPTY_SPACE -lt $ARCHIVE_SIZE ]` passes and would save the output of `tar czf - "$1"` to the disk.

One other idea for solving it was to save it temporarily in a variable, but saving a potentially multi GB file in a bash variable seems like just asking for trouble.

I've looked at the [conditional pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38310/conditional-pipeline) post on the Unix StackExchange, but that only covers a conditional pipeline, and I can't (that I know of) use the same output of the `tar czf - "$1"` in 2 consecutive pipeline parts.

Comment: How about creating a Ramdisk and temporarily save the compressed file there?

Comment: @tshiono How would I go about doing that? And do you mean save the file on the ramdisk, check its size there, and if there's space chuck it onto the physical drive? Wouldn't that create a problem with files that are larger than the ammount of RAM, or is that already a problem when sending them to STDOUT?

Comment: Right. You need to adjust the size of Ramdisk large enough to store the file. As you comment, too large file will cause problem anyway unless you allow compressing twice.

Comment: If the compressed file is so large that it does not fit into your RAM, you are out of luck, and storing into a variable wouldn't work either (the variable has to fit into RAM as well). But if your file system is so full that it may not even have space for the **compressed** file, you will be in trouble soon anyway. For practical reason, I would just test whether there is enough space for the size of the **uncompressed** data, and if this is not the case, I would report the error.  Alternatively, you can simply try to compress it and catch the _not enough space_ error.

Comment: @user1934428 Catching the "not enough space" error seems like a better idea, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: In theory, you could catch the stderr of tar and analyze the message, but I would make it more general, and look at the exit code of `tar`. If something goes wrong, the exit-code is non-zero (look at the variable `PIPESTATUS` in the bash man-page), and the error message, which is displayed to stderr anyway, tells the user about the reason.